# APACHE server run slow suddenly

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I'm using Apache for my localhost,  bot now it's slowed down without any error suddenly, each time I start load a page it takes more than 1 minute , I do see any uncommon error in the error log , and my PHP code is also run perfectly without error.

I had tried several solution like adding localhost, `enablemmap` on off, setting only `IPv4` but and non of it helping.

Is that anything more i can try to fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Please, add code. May be something wrong in it. Or try execute script on hosting.

Comment: check `top` on the server.

Comment: @CnapoB The code run perfectly on hosting server , just localhost for development slow

Comment: How you install apache+php? Manually or inside some pack (Denver etc.). Try install manually. Instructions can be finding by Google (I found on my own language). Please write, what type of OS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by re-installing Apache server.